# FileNet P8 disable subscription event action

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I am working on FileNet P8 5.2.1 and I am wondering what is the best practice in order to disable an event action and a subscription :

- subscription disabled event action disabled
- subscription disabled event action enabled
- subscription enabled event action disabled

Did you ever had some trouble with one of these cases?
This third case (subscription enabled / event action disabled) is reallya wonder to me. I doubt it is a good practice to have but what happens if the subscription is triggered? Does the subscription try to launch the event action and eventually ends up with an error or does it do nothing?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subscription is what triggers your event action. So if you disable subscription, event action will not be triggered.
If you keep subscription enable but disable the action, it throws an error.

if you disable both then it is safer...

I would take the third approach if I don't want event action to be executed.

Comment: thank you! I tested it and it didn't throw any error, it feels safe to take the third approach :)